# Show modal Boostrap when click button

Tags: html, jquery, css, jsp

I have a problem in my code. If i click button search in my form when one field have input, i get the button SEARCH with the popup in the same time.

But i want to show the popup only when i click the button SEARCH.

The code html is in this link: https://jsfiddle.net/ge5zxmst/

```js
ACC.multiLogin = {
  _autoload: [
    "inputField",
    "popUpModal"
  ],
  inputField: function() {
    var showHideButtonSearch = () => {
      let hasValue = false;
      
      $("#multiLogin-search input.text-input").each(function() {
        if ($(this).val()) {
          hasValue = true;
        }
      });
      
      if (hasValue === false) {
        $(".button-row [name=search]").hide();
      } else {
        $(".button-row [name=search]").show();
      }
    }
    
    // Check input values on key up
    $("#multiLogin-search input.text-input").keyup(function() {
      showHideButtonSearch();
    });

    //Hide button search on page load
    showHideButtonSearch();
  },
  popUpModal: function() {
    $(".button-row [name=search]").show().on("click", function() {
      $('.pop-outer').fadeIn('slow');
    });

    $(".close").on("click", function() {
      $('.pop-outer').fadeOut('slow');
    });
  },
}
```

```css
.pop-outer {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.pop-inner {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300%;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 15% auto;
}
```

Thank you for helping.

Comment: I see that you're new and I'm sure that English isn't your first language. Please have a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question. In particular, you're missing a problem statement so it isn't clear what you want to achieve or what your code is doing different.

Comment: i edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few corrections to make in your script. Don't use space after the button class.

```
$(".button-row[name=search]")  <-- Correct
$(".button-row [name=search]") <-- Wrong
```

To show the popup use the script as below.

```
$(".button-row[name=search]").on("click", function() {
  $('.pop-outer').fadeIn('slow');
});

$("button.close").on("click", function() {
  $('.pop-outer').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

**Updated**:

I have moved the popup html out of the form tag and used appropriate attribute tags to show & hide the modal.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form id="multiLogin-search" class="d-none">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="text-input-wrap">
      <p> Customer number <p>
      <p> <input class="text-input" type="text" name="customerCode"  > <p>
    </div>
    <div class="text-input-wrap">
      <p> Country <p>
      <p> <input class="text-input" type="text" name="country"  > <p>

    </div>
    <div class="text-input-wrap">
      <p> Postal Code <p>

      <p> <input class="text-input" type="text" name="postalCode"  > <p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="text-input-wrap">
      <p> Customer Name <p>
      <p> <input class="text-input" type="text" name="customerName" > <p>
    </div>
    <div class="text-input-wrap">
      <p> City <p>
      <p> <input class="text-input" type="text" name="city" > <p>
    </div>
    <div class="text-input-wrap">
      <p> Address <p>
      <p> <input class="text-input" type="text" name="address"><p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="button-row">
    <button class="btn btn-black" type="button" name="search"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><spring:theme code="multilogin.search.button"/>Search</button>
  </div>
</form>
            
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="pop-inner">
          <h2>This is an example of modal Boostrap</h2>
          <p>You can use all Bootstrap plugins purely through the markup API without writing a single line of JavaScript.
            This is Bootstraps first-class API and should be your first consideration when using a plugin.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Even so, i've the same problem. I get button and popup at the same time. Could be the problem in the html code?

Comment: The button appears and the popup get opened without click event on the button?

Comment: yes. i've the popup above the button (SEARCH) because i can't click it

Comment: Check my updated answer to understand how to use bootstrap modal without jquery scripts

Comment: Thank you so much @Zam Abdul Vahid. Your answers are always clear and well detailed.

Comment: Glad i was able to help.